# execute good method at runtime

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I created a class Message with several Inheritances (UserMessage extends Message, BotMessage extends Message, ...)

In a service class BotService I have the following methods:

```
private void dealWithMessage(Message message) {
    loadMessage(message);
}

private void loadMessage(UserMessage message) {
    LOGGER.info("it's a user message");
}

private void loadMessage(BotMessage message) {
     LOGGER.info("it's a bot message");
}

private void loadMessage(Message message) {
     LOGGER.info("I do not expect to go here");
}
```

I do not want to add loadMessage() method in UserMessage and BotMessage classes.
How can I acheive to go in specific loadMessage methods at runtime please (for the moment it always go in the last method with Message class parameter)? Should I use generic type in some way ?

thank you

Comment: You _could_ do the different behavior using `instanceof`. But if possible it would be much better if you can solve this by changing the architecture. Generics, if applicable in your situation, would be one way to solve it. But then again, you would route all of them into the same method and the different behavior could be implemented inside the specific message class (maybe delegated to a dedicated object), and not centralized in the service, if possible. Otherwise I doubt you can get rid of any sort of _"if this or that ..."_ check in the service. Hard to argue without having more insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Visitor pattern:

```
interface MessageVisitor {
  void visitUserMessage(UserMessage message);
  void visitBotMessage(BotMessage message);
}
```

Then add to your `Message` interface:

```
...
void accept(MessageVisitor visitor);
...
```

Which is implemented as:

```
class UserMessage implements Message {
...
void accept(MessageVisitor visitor) {
   visitor.visitUserMessage(this);
}
```

and

```
class BotMessage implements Message {
...
void accept(MessageVisitor visitor) {
   visitor.visitBotMessage(this);
}
```

so `loadMessage` looks like:

```
MessageVisitor visitor = new MessageVisitor() {
   void visitUserMessage(UserMessage message) {
      LOGGER.info("it's a user message");
   }
      void visitBotMessage(UserMessage message) {
      LOGGER.info("it's a bot message");
   }
}

message.accept(visitor);
```

The nice thing about this is that if you create a new class which implements `Message` you are forced to implement `accept`, which will prompt you to add a new method to `MessageVisitor`, and so add its implementation to all `MessageVisitor` implementations. Using `instanceof` allows you to forget to add new cases to your code when new classes are introduced.

It also keeps your business logic separate from your Message classes -- they just implement the mechanism of the visitor pattern, not any actual functionality.

Comment: I already thought about this solution, but I do not want to change my Messages classes as they are only DTO.

Comment: After thinking a little bit more about your proposal, I think it's a good way to made it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that at runtime, inside your `dealWithMessage` method the `message` object is of the class `Message`. Even if you pass a `UserMessage` instance, this method will only know the characteristics of the `Message` class.
That's why your last `loadMessage(Message message)` is always called.

A quick fix (not elegant but quick) would be `instanceOf` in your `dealWithMessage` method:

```
private void dealWithMessage(Message message) {
    if(message instanceOf UserMessage){         // check if object is instance of subclass
        loadMessage((UserMessage) message);     // cast to subclass
    } else if(message instanceOf BotMessage){   // the same thing for all other subclasses
        loadMessage((BotMessage) message);   
    } else {
        loadMessage(message);                    // "generic" fall back
    }
}
```

another possibility would be overloading the `dealWithMessage` method, the same way you overloaded the `loadMessage` methods:

```
 private void dealWithMessage(UserMessage message){ 
     loadMessage(message);  // here no casting is necessary, since the object is already known to be a UserMessage instance
 } 

 private void dealWithMessage(BotMessage message){ 
     loadMessage(message);  
 }
```

Comment: I though about "instance of" but I do not want to do that... If I overload dealWithMessage as you suggest, the problem will be the same but at a different level, isn't it ?

Comment: at some point, before you call "dealWithMessage" your object is either an instance of `UserMessage` or `BotMessage`, right? If you call `dealWithMessage` with either a `User..` or a `BotMessage` then  it will work.  Only if the calling function does no longer know the precise type of your message object, then it will be the same problem.

Comment: I never know the type as I get the messge from a rest point : @POST
    public void load(Message message) {...}